# Unravelling a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to transform a df into antoher, being the original (df1) like this:

```
           value
    A--A     4     
    A--B     2     
    A--C     1    
    B--B     2    
    C--C     3    
    D--B     2    
    E--E     6
```

Then I have this other df2, filled with 0:

```
        A    B    C    D    E
    A   0    0    0    0    0
    B   0    0    0    0    0
    C   0    0    0    0    0
    D   0    0    0    0    0
    E   0    0    0    0    0
    F   0    0    0    0    0
    G   0    0    0    0    0
```

I need to convert it to a final df3, getting the values from the pairs in the index from df1, separted by "--", and fill it like this:

```
        A    B    C    D    E
    A   4    2    1    0    0
    B   2    2    0    2    0
    C   1    0    3    0    0
    D   0    2    0    0    0
    E   0    0    0    0    6
    F   0    0    0    0    0
    G   0    0    0    0    0
```

There can be pairs in pd2 not existing in pd1. It that case it remains with 0. Any suggestions??

Comment: pd usually stands for Pandas here, which is the package name. perhaps you mean df which stands for dataframe (or table)?

Comment: Could you add the code for the creation of the dataframe?

Comment: df.index gives you the list of locations where you want to change values. df2.loc[row, col] allows you to access the respective position in the big dataframe.

Comment: @AsheKetchum can you give further explanation or example code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this from `df` itself. First, set `df.index` to a `MultiIndex` using `str.split`, and then `unstack` and `reindex`.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.index.str.split('--')))
(df['value'].unstack()
            .reindex(index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns)
            .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

   A  B  C  D  E
A  4  2  1  0  0
B  0  2  0  0  0
C  0  0  3  0  0
D  0  2  0  0  0
E  0  0  0  0  6
F  0  0  0  0  0
G  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

If you know what rows and columns you want to use, you don't even need `df2`.

```
(df['value'].unstack()
            .reindex(index=list('ABCDEFG'), columns=list('ABCDE'))
            .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

   A  B  C  D  E
A  4  2  1  0  0
B  0  2  0  0  0
C  0  0  3  0  0
D  0  2  0  0  0
E  0  0  0  0  6
F  0  0  0  0  0
G  0  0  0  0  0
```

---

As per OP's comment, to maintain symmetricity, use pivot your table so NaNs are preserved, then `fillna` with the transpose:

```
v = (df['value'].unstack()
                .reindex(index=df2.index, columns=df2.columns))
v.fillna(v.T.reindex_like(v)).fillna(0, downcast='infer')

   A  B  C  D  E
A  4  2  1  0  0
B  2  2  0  2  0
C  1  0  3  0  0
D  0  2  0  0  0
E  0  0  0  0  6
F  0  0  0  0  0
G  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: actually it's not exactly the solution, because A - C is 1, but C - A is 0. Since A - C and C - A are the same thing I need the value in both places. And when I print df it has 2 cols for ids instead of 1 col and 1 header (row)